# Throwing custom exceptions in multi-layered spring project

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, exception, dao

I am trying to handle the use case where there's a violation for an unique field (for example, the username/mail), would it be correct to handle it like so? (I am using jdbcInsert on the dao layer)

```
@Transactional
@Override
public User register(String name, String surname, String username, String email, String password) {
    User user = null;
    try {
        user = userDao.register(name, surname, username,
                email, passwordEncoder.encode(password));
    } catch (DuplicateKeyException duplicateKeyException) {
        throw new DuplicateUserException(duplicateKeyException.getMessage());
    } catch (DataAccessException dataAccessException) {
        throw new SystemUnavailableException(dataAccessException.getMessage());
    }
    return user;
}
```

And catching my custom exceptions in the controller:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ErrorControllerAdvice {
    @ExceptionHandler(DuplicateUserException.class)
    public ModelAndView keyViolation(DuplicateUserException ex) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("admin/user/new");
        mav.addObject("duplicateMessage", ex.getErrorMessage());
        return mav;
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(SystemUnavailableException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    public ModelAndView unexpectedDatabaseError(SystemUnavailableException ex) {
        LOGGER.error(ex.getErrorMessage());
        return new ModelAndView("500");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks fine to me. Your custom exceptions live at a different level of abstraction, which gives them good reason for existing.

You might consider handling the exceptions in your controller, instead of using an Error translator class (`ErrorControllerAdvice`) though. This makes things more explicit and limit surprises about how exceptions are handled.